# Chi-square test for uniform sample gives the wrong result

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

I'm studing $\chi^2$ test. I generated sample size 50 elements of uniform distribution ($U(x, \frac{-3}{2}, \frac{3}{2})$). After that, I assume that it has the form $N(x, 0, 1)$ and take it as the null hypothesis $H_0$. I checked the null hypothesis using the chi-squared test $\chi^2$ and $\alpha = 0.05$ as a significance point.

The result confused me a little bit. The thing is that the hypothesis $H_0$ is in line with the sample. Obviously, it’s the wrong result.

How that result can be explained? Is it due to the choice of distribution parameters or what?

Comment: Can it be that you actually want to test the SAMPLING distribution of the mean? So, you would need, for example, $ 50$ samples of size $50$ and you would test the sample mean for being normally distributed?

Comment: $50$ is not a particularly large sample size - the chances that $50$ normally distributed points will all lie between $-3/2$ and $3/2$ and sort-of look like they are uniformly distributed are not that low.  BTW It is generally better to use the Shapiro-Wilk test to test for normality rather than the Chi-squared test.